# Whether a battery is a constant voltage source or current source

Tags: batteries

is battery is a constant voltage source or constant current source?if it is a voltage source then why the voltage gets dropped?if it is a current source?is really the battery is providing electrons to the conductor?

Comment: Neither. It's one or more electrochemical cells.

Comment: Under no load it has a 'constant' potential.  When loaded the chemistry presents as internal resistance and the voltage will drop.  As the chemistry shifts with discharge (or charge) the no load voltage changes slightly and the internal resistance changes as well.

Answer (score 6):

A battery is considered to be a voltage source because the galvanic activity they use to store and deliver energy has a fixed voltage across it.

However, a battery is not an ideal voltage source.  All real sources have some built in resistance.  In the case of a battery, the effect is well modeled as an ideal voltage source in series with a small resistor (I don't know numbers, but I'd expect it to be single digit ohms).  Thus, when you draw current from the battery, the voltage across the resistor goes up which means the voltage across your circuit goes down.

Eventually you deplete the battery.  When this happens, we can no longer treat all of the parts of the battery in bulk.  Parts of the battery will remain charged, other parts will be fully discharged.  During this time, we have to use an even more complicated model to describe the battery.  Which model you use would depend on the particular battery failure characteristics.  However, the most visible effect is that, when there is no circuit connected, we can measure a voltage across the battery that is lower than the ideal expected voltage based on the galvanic properties of the battery.

Answer (score 4):

depends on the internal resistance of the battery.

the battery can, under normal circumstances, be either a Thevenin equivalent or a Norton equivalent.

in the Thevenin model the battery is a constant voltage source in series with the internal resistance.

in the Norton model the battery is a constant current source in parallel with the internal resistance.

if the internal resistance is very low compared to the load, the battery is connected to, looking at it as a Thevenin model (a voltage source) makes more sense.

if the internal resistance is very high compared to the load the battery is connected to, looking at it as a Norton model (a current source) makes more sense.

Answer (score -3):

It's a constant voltage source,  the value of current being drained out of it depends on the load. A 1kw 12v motor will drain more current from the battery than a 0.5 kw 12v.  The voltage value is constant,  current changes according to the power required by the load.

Comment: A word "constant" is not very appropriate in this case.

Comment: The question is about why battery terminal voltage decreases with load. Your answer does not address this.